# Are there connections between the theory of computation and machine learning?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, machine-learning

I am wondering if studying the Theory of Computation/ Computational Complexity theory, specifically Sipser's 'Introduction to the Theory of Computation' will help me do machine learning/statistics/data science better. Are there any connections? I intend to study the book even if there aren't any connections.

Comment: The connection is via *statistical learning theory*, but at the moment it seems rather tenuous, at least as far as deep learning is concerned.

Comment: If you're interested in artificial intelligence, then go for it, machine learning is just the area of specialisation.Computation Theory is on its own....!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out [Computational learning theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_learning_theory) (Algorithmic learning theory) and conferences COLT and ALT although the connection with machine learning is arguably limited.